# a simple Inequality with an integral

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, complex-integration

Reading a thesis it appear the following inequality:
$$\frac{N}{2\pi}\int_{-\theta}^{\theta}e^{t\epsilon \cos(s)}ds \leq \frac{\theta N e}{\pi}, $$
where $t \in [\epsilon, \infty)$, $\theta \in (\pi/2,\pi)$. I thought about to use that $\cos(s) \leq 1$, but
$$\int_{-\theta}^{\theta}e^{t\epsilon}ds=2\theta e^{t\epsilon}$$
different of $2\theta e$. I suspect that it involves something of polar variables, because the integral begin as a complex integral.

Comment: This cannot be true since $$
\int_{ - \theta }^\theta  {e^{t\varepsilon \cos (s)} ds}  \ge \int_{ - \pi /3}^{\pi /3} {e^{t\varepsilon \cos (s)} ds}  \ge \int_{ - \pi /3}^{\pi /3} {e^{t\varepsilon /2} ds}  = \frac{{2\pi }}{3}e^{t\varepsilon /2}  \to  + \infty 
$$ as $t\to +\infty$ (provided $\epsilon>0$).